# Getting error (0 , _schemaUtils.default) is not a function when running CRA on Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

## Update

Fixed it by running

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && yarn && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
```

---

I'm having trouble running my app with Docker.

Fist, I build the image,

```
// build image
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    print:
        stdin_open: true
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - '.:/app'
            - '/app/node_modules'
```

`Dockerfile.dev`:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "pprb-frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.11",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "formik": "^2.2.5",
        "history": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.0",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "reload": "rm -rf node_modules && yarn",
        "reload:start": "yarn reload && yarn start"
    },
}
```

What's going on here? I took a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881883/2891356), but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Docker image, if necessary is: `docker pull mkhoussid/cra_img:secondtry`. Running it throws the error,

```
(0 , _schemaUtils.default) is not a function
```

## Edit

I've run the below:

```
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune
$ docker rmi $(sudo docker images -aq) --force
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: Try `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`. Did you clean your docker with prune?

Comment: Yes, I edited the OP

Comment: Did you set your .dockerignore with node_modules? My package.json is as complex as your and everything is ok now.

Comment: Perhaps should you try rebuilding your yarn.lock or package-lock.json.

Comment: I fixed it by running `rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && yarn && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`. Very strange

Comment: I tried so many things before take it running. I don't know why removing node_modules solves the problem because it should be rebuilt by docker and not copied due to the dockerignore. Which is not the case of lock file.

Comment: I think it was an issue with `yarn.lock`, not `node_modules`, because this was the first time that I deleted and rebuilt the `yarn.lock` file since running `create-react-app` command. I'm willing to bet that if you run a fresh `npx create-react-app test_app` command and then run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`, then it will fail. If my bet is right, then the fix is to run the command [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897545/getting-error-0-schemautils-default-is-not-a-function-when-running-cra-on-d?noredirect=1#comment114740518_64897545)

Comment: Had the same problem, though using npm, not yarn. Fixed it by deleting node_modules first. Thank you, @MikeK !